# What was the buzz over everipedia airdrop and what is it exactly?

Tags: airdrops, everipedia

What is everipedia and why was there such a buzz over its air drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everipedia is the world's first encyclopedia on the blockchain,It's also the biggest english encyclopedia at present.

Everipedia's IQ Network is the world's first Encyclopedia that allows anyone to become a stakeholder in the system and earn rank, rewards & tokens for curating content. I guess you can get more details from following everipedia page:https://everipedia.org/wiki/everipedia/

Comment: where is the data stored